# ARM While directive - repeating labels

Tags: assembly, while-loop, arm, directive, arm7

If using the WHILE asm directive, intialised like:

```
    GBLA    w
    WHILE   w < 10
w   SETA    w+1
    ; code
    WEND
```

How can we have `;code` be a repeated segment involving a label (say, we conditionally branch back to it in the segment)?

I have tried doing:

```
w.label    ;code
           ;code
           B{cond}    w.label
```

And also `label.w`.

I also tried forming a macro, with `w` passed in as a parameter, but it didn't want to join `label` to a numeric value in that way.

Does `.` only work for strings, and if so can I concatenate a string and a literal in some other way?

Or what other way can I include a label in a segment to be repeated `w` times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the reasons [local labels](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473c/Caccjfff.html) exist:

```
1:    ;code
      ;code
      B{cond}    1b    @ look (b)ackwards for the nearest "1:"
```

Since these always resolve to the last/next match seen, and don't generate symbols, they can be unambiguously duplicated as much as you like.